# Why a node-based binary connects to registry.npmjs.org at run-time?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm experimenting with `@remix-project/remixd`. I'm installing the package with a plain `npm install -g @remix-project/remixd`.

Anyhow, I need to run the `remixd command` on an air-gapped system. When I start it, it fails with `EAI_AGAIN trying to connect to registry.npmjs.org`.

It can't connect because the system is air-gapped but why that happens in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why that happens in the first place?

[Apparently](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/blob/e8b7f0cdd0a574d280613a50ee3a05f59a952436/libs/remixd/src/bin/remixd.ts#L15-L25) `remixd` contacts the npm registry at start to check whether you're running the latest version using the [`latest-version`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/latest-version) package.

There doesn't seem to be a way to turn this behavior off.

Comment: Stupid me, I thought it was something related to npm itself. Anyway, thanks for sparing me the time to look for it by providing the link to the piece of code that's doing that. I'll be disabling the check in my environment by amending the code. Maybe I will make a pull request to the remix-project to have a command line switch. Thanks again!